# Zombie connections after hosting

Tags: java, mysql, database, host

I have an application developed with Java using MySQL and C3P0 for connection pooling. The application works perfectly fine in localhost, the connection management was superb. However, I uploaded this application to `Daily Razor` "private JVM", and here we go, there were lot of MySQL connections than the application will ever make! Normally the application will make max 10 connections, but when I hosted there I can see 30 or more.

Apart from that, I always had number of mysql processors running in my localhost, but when uploaded to the online server I can only see 2. It is like upside down. The application works fine but there were number of times that I had to restart the server due to slow connection issue.

What is making this kind of thing? Anyway pls don't ask for code, because I don't know where the issue is